# Linksys SRW2024 switching/backplane capacity

Tags: networking, switch, linksys

I have one of these switches. Its switching capacity is rated as 48Gbps non-blocking, which I suppose is a "marketing trick" made of 24-port 1Gbps on full-duplex. If I understand correctly this means I can load all 24 ports and expect 1Gbps per port. Well, this is not the case.

How to find out the real switching capacity?

Thanks

Edit: How to find out if the switch can sustain full load (48Gbps)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what it means, all ports can transmit inbound and outbound at 1Gbps - i.e. 24 x (1+1) = 48.

Comment: Then why some enterprise switches have 144Gbps switching capacity?

Comment: Because they either have either more and/or faster ports or are capable of taking more of these.

Comment: Some Cisco switches are also stackable and the big backplane is good for future grow.